# JAVA Sockets getting called too many times

Tags: java, sockets, socketserver

I am trying to implement an ServerSocket but i simply can not understand why code gets called 3 times if I close the connection. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int port = 8080;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        out.println("Listening ..");

        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            out.println("Connected" + socket.getLocalAddress());
            new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(socket)).start();
        }

    }
}



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class MultiThreadServer implements  Runnable{

    Socket clientSocket;

    MultiThreadServer(Socket clientSocket){ this.clientSocket = clientSocket;};

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            out.println("inside thread");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String request = bufferedReader.readLine();
            out.println("request: " + request);
            bufferedReader.close();
            this.clientSocket.close(); //Without this line, the code is only called once
        }catch(IOException e){
            out.println(e);
        }

    }


}
```

So, by calling the close() method on the clientSocket would call the called inside "while(true)" 3 times, while without calling the method, it would be called once.
Here is the log WITH socket.close() :

```
Listening ..
Connected/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
inside thread
request: GET /tttes HTTP/1.1
Connected/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
inside thread
request: GET /tttes HTTP/1.1
Connected/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
inside thread
request: GET /tttes HTTP/1.1
```

Here is the log WITHOUT socket.close():

```
Listening ..
Connected/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
inside thread
request: GET /tttes HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely that your client is waiting for the data from your server and isn't trying to connect again until the previous connection has closed.  This would explain the behaviour you see.

If you have multiple concurrent clients, one connection doesn't know you are not going to close the connection for an unrelated connection.

Comment: Hmm, but without closing the client socket, I can still connect as other client, so I can have multiple concurrent clients

Comment: @Angelo so I would say the client is the one which needs the connection to be closed before it will open another one.

Comment: As i said, if I close it, it would go through the "while(true)" loop 3 times / actual request. I can not figure it out why is that

Comment: @Angelo The issue is in the client code, so it's hard to say without seeing the client's code.

Comment: There is no client code. I am simply connecting via Chrome to http://localhost:8080

Comment: @Angelo then you need to read the code of Chrome. In any case, I would assume chrome waits for the output stream to be closed so it can receive all the data the GET requests before making another call.